# Exception Handling questions java

Tags: java, exception

I have 2 questions in my mind please help me resolving this.

1.can I throw runtime exception?

2.what is the hierarachy for userdefine exception?

For example I have filenot found, user define and an exception ..3 catch
Try block can throw any. So how to keep hierarchy(I know subclass on top.super below..but doubt for user define exception)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can google for this.

Comment: Don't ask multiple questions in one post, and do a little research on your questions before posting them.

Comment: checked in Google.found not proper answer.if u can find answer in Google.please share me urls.thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can throw a `RuntimeException`.
2. You can define your own exception classes, so you decide yourself what the class hierarchy is.

See [Java Tutorial: Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

Comment: "you decide yourself what the class hierarchy is" - as long as it at least extends `Throwable`...

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly want to throw user defined exceptions, you should uses throw  and method signature should say throws

Coming to your second question, exceptions should be caught from specific to general, I mean exception A, followed by exception B (where B encompasses A) there on. With this you can handle individual exceptions differently.